# start a docker container in user mode with read-write access permission

Tags: docker, containers

I try to start a new container from ubuntu 18.04 docker image. I do as follows:

1. pull the docker image

   `docer pull ubuntu:18.04`
2. create a new container

   `docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/home/shared --name ubuntu_test ubuntu:18.04`

   and then log out.
3. start the created container

   `docker start ubuntu_test`
4. log in as root user, update OS and install `vim`

   `docker exec -ti ubuntu_test /bin/bash` and `apt update`, `apt install -y vim`

   then log out.
5. log in as non-root user

   `docker exec -ti -u daemon ubuntu_test /bin/bash`

   Then I found that I have no permission to create new files or new folders.

I do not want to log in as root user since there could be some problems with `mpirun`.

Is there any solution for this problem ? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not like you (non-root user) don't have permissions to write or read. It is that everything on the system (files/folders) belong to the root user and no other user can modify anything by default.

You can create a new user as well as home folder for that user when you are building the image and then the user will be able to modify stuff in its home (standard linux stuff).

Example Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN groupadd --gid 1000 someuser \
    && useradd --uid 1000 --gid someuser --shell /bin/bash --create-home someuser
```

test with

```
docker build -t utest .
docker container run -it -u someuser utest /bin/bash
cd /home/someuser
touch myfile
```

If you need to add some other folders under that user's administration other than its home, you can use `chown -R someuser:someuser <folder>` which will recursively change ownership of the specified folder and everything in it to that of the new user.

Example: changing ownership of `/etc` folder

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN groupadd --gid 1000 someuser \
    && useradd --uid 1000 --gid someuser --shell /bin/bash --create-home someuser 

RUN chown -R someuser:someuser /etc
```